# If checkbox is checked add class to it's label

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add class to checkbox label if checkbox is already checked.
i am doing this with jQuery each function but it adds class to all checkboxes label when i refresh the page.

```
$('label.checkbox').each(function() {
if ($('.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
    $('label.checkbox').addClass('checked');
}
});
```

HTML

```
    <label class="checkbox">
        <span>Title</span>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="" />
    </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the jQuery [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector, you could select all checked input elements and then add the class to the parent label element. No need for a loop.

```
$('input:checked').parent('label').addClass('checked');
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/290o2hvb/)